# Как получить время ответа отправки сообщения vk_api

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Очень часто видел как многие боты отправляли ответ "время отклика: 0.173837473" (к примеру)
На сообщение "ping"
Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если найдёте в VkAPI, то можно узнать время отправки сообщения. А в конце кода, перед самой отправкой сообщения ботом, можно узнать текущее время (тем же datetime). Ну и вычесть второе из первого. Это вам в документацию `datetime`. Или же вы можете отсчитывать время между принятием сообщения и отправкой. Тут уже только datetime понадобится. Выбор за вами!

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, все получилось